# additional field with XUpload in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-xupload

Im new to Yii framework and im using yii [xupload](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/xupload/) extension for multiple file upload. It's working fine. Now, my problem is i don't know how to add additional fields, like Title(text field), Category(listbox) with this xupload form. Please help.

My code in view is,

```
$this->widget('xupload.XUpload', array(
                'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("site/upload"),
                'model' => $model,
                'attribute' => 'file',
                'multiple' => true,
));
```

Comment: Is `$model` an `XUploadForm`?

Comment: yes. Here $model is an XUploadForm.

Answer (score 1):

[Additional form data with XUpload](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/395/additional-form-data-with-xupload/) its a wiki that describes exactly how to do what you want

Comment: Hello Sir, I've trying to understand how to post some hidden fields when uploading. I don't understand why it is not possible to add this fields to the array and access them in the form.php like array(
                'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("site/upload"),
                'model' => $model,
                'attribute' => 'file',
                'multiple' => true, 'x'=>$x, 'y'=>$y, 'z'=>$z,
). The http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/395/additional-form-data-with-xupload/ doesn't mention how to use php variables. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: The array to which you are adding the values is for configuration, it wont send that data along in the form. what you need to do, is add the hidden fields to the templates as explained in the wiki

Comment: Hello @Asgaroth, is there any way to use yii xupload in another form? the problem is xupload form.php has a form tag, so it can not be included in another form.

Comment: @HPM check out this [wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/348/xupload-workflow/), basically you have to provide your own form template, excluding the form tag, which allows to also add extra fields if you need to.

Comment: You've done a great job, but why you didn't handle this widget without form tag? In that  way your widget could have been used anywhere without any more effort! Please don't think that I'm a lazy guy, I just want to extend my knowledge about creating a Yii widget.

Comment: @HPM It depends on perspective, sometimes people simply needs to upload images, in that case it is an out of the box functionality, they don't have to do anything, in other cases it requires a little bit of configuration, not sure what's the mayority of users.